# How to Permanently redirect URLs based on conditions

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

everyone

I will be very much grateful if anyone can help me with the correct **.htaccess rules** to permanently redirect all URLs that meet the criteria ==

domain.com/category/subcategory/**123456**-some-article-title.html

or domain.com/category/**NNNNNN**-some-article-title.html   (where **NNNNNN** is any number as shown in the first url.)

to the same url without the numbers preceding the article title. like this

**domain.com/category/subcategory/some-article-title.html**

the first URL Structure has the article IDs which I no longer want to keep.

is there anyway I can make this happen?

Comment: Users asking questions are expected to show the effort they made at solving their problem.  Show us your best attempt and someone will probably help you polish it.

Comment: There are many resources on the Internet that explain how to write .htaccess rules. Please read them and if you have a specific question about writing an .htaccess rule working feel free to come back and ask while telling us what you tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are tons of ways of doing this. It also depends what modules are enabled and what you can do in your .htaccess file.

I prefer using `mod_rewrite` for rules like this. You can do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/.+)/[0-9]+-([^/]+)$ $1/$2 [R=permanent]
```

I'm assuming that "category" and "subcategory" are just placeholders and it cant be any path and that "some-article-title.html" doesn't start with numbers.

`^` Start of path part of URL (i.e., don't match in the middle)

`(/.+)` Path = $1

`/[0-9]+-` Last slash, numbers, and dash

`([^/]+)$` Everything to the end can't contain / = $2

`$1/$2` Replace URL with path/file.

`[R=permanent]` Flag R is redirect

You will need to test and customize this for your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @melds. I tried this but it didn't work. The pages kept generating 404s. I also tried 
`RewriteRule  ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/[0-9]+-/([a-z0-9]+.html)$ $1/$2/$4 [R]`   which just kept showing me the requested URL itself on the page. Other people in other forums say it is impossible for mod_rewrite to change a files name as in my case dropping the preceding numbers. I appreciate any help that comes.

Comment: I finally got a Plugin to do the work. Thank you all for the help.  [link](https://foobla.com/joomla-goodies/massive-redirects)